# Android App Bundle does not include a file inside /src/main/asset

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

we have a Gradle task that adds a `data.json` file to `src/main/assets`. Not sure exactly why they decided it. Anyways, when I switched to App Bundle and uploaded it to Play Store app crashes with

```
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.json
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:876)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:853)
```

It seems like the json file is not included in the app, is there a way to tell App Bundle to also include that file?

I have read about [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-native), but this is too much refactoring, and the .json file is less than 1 MB

Comment: I assume you need to change when you run this task, e.g. instead of doing it before `assemble`, you'd need to do it before `assembleBundle` or similar. Without seeing how the task is plugged in, hard to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pierre, I was able to fix this.

The task was added like this

```
afterEvaluate {
    mergeDebugResources.dependsOn updateDataDebug
    mergeQaResources.dependsOn updateDataQa
    mergeReleaseResources.dependsOn updateDataProduction
}
```

changed it to this and now it works. Could not find much documentation about this, but at least it works...

```
afterEvaluate {
    mergeDebugAssets.dependsOn updateDataDebug
    mergeQaAssets.dependsOn updateDataQa
    mergeReleaseAssets.dependsOn updateDataProduction
}
```